# How to know when a float variable is going to stop increasing by 0.001?

Tags: binary, double, computer-science, break, representation

I want to know how to determine at wich value a float (or double) variable is going to stop increasing its value if I am increasing it by 0.001.

If we talk about the binary representation of the float value: 1 bit for Sign, 8 exponent bits and 23 bits for mantissa. We know that when we reach a determined high value (32768) and then we add a very small value (0.001), due to the EXC 127 representation of the exponent, the addition result will be:

```
32768 + 0 = 32768
```

According to that, the variable will have the same value eventhough we are adding 0.001.

The next code never breaks.

```
float max =100000;
float delta=0.001F;
float time = 0;
while (time < max)
{
time += delta;
if(time == max)
    break;
}
```

Can someone help me to determine an ecuation to know when a variable is going to stop increasing? (Independently if it is a float or a double, the idea is to have a floating comma variable).

Comment: I'll just note here that it's impossible to increase a float variable by exactly .001, or even to represent .001 exactly as a float.  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your addition will become idempotent (that is, the result will not change) after `time` gets large enough that the size of its [ULP (unit in the last place)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) is greater than the size of your `delta`.

Answer (score 0):

Your **time** variable is by default greater than **max** variable.

Answer (score -1):

It's REALLY simple:
time is never gonna equal max if time starts off with 215100 and max is 100000 as long as you are adding some positive number to time. Also, comparing floats is kinda problematic due to float-imprecision.

To answer your question for an equation:
addition will fail completely if

```
[(log a)/(log 2)]<[((log b)/(log 2))^-c]
```

Where

- a is your small float you want to add
- b is your large fliat you want to add on
- c is the length of the mantissa (23 for float)

Comment: @Sebastian still, comparing floats with == is inadequate, use >=